# Explain in words an assumption on a function

Tags: functions, terminology

Consider a function $(X,\epsilon)\mapsto f(X,\epsilon)$ where

- $X$ is a vector $K\times 1$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}^K$
- $\epsilon$ is a vector $M\times 1$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}^M$
- $f(X,\epsilon)\in \mathbb{R}$

I would like your help to explain in words the following assumption:

$$
(\star) \hspace{1cm} f(X,\epsilon)\equiv g(X)+v(\epsilon)
$$
with $g: \mathbb{R}^K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $v: \mathbb{R}^M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Is it correct to say "It is assumed that $f$ is additively separable over $X$ and $\epsilon$"? I am not convinced about it. Do you have better suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if there is any standard wording for this, but I quite like your suggestion. Just make sure that you provide the reader with $(\star)$ the first time that you use this wording in your work.

Comment: I think assumptions are generally worded: "Let x be a something-or-other where something-else-is-true... ." Definitions are important if the terms are not obvious.